# Why can't I use ._doc_ attribute for built in functions?

Tags: python

For example:

```
print(print._doc_)
```

this is the error I get:

```
PS D:\GitHub\Mango> py temp.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\Mango\temp.txt", line 1, in <module>
    print(print._doc_)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '_doc_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `__doc__` (two underscores on either side):

```
>>> print(print.__doc__)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Comment: Ahh! I see! Thanks, it makes sense now. It looks like a single underscore.

Comment: @TangoMango28 It may help to use fonts designed that using double-underscores will have a clear/distinct separation, and don't look like 1 big underscore (as how it's rendered here in SO).

Comment: tekknolagi thank you! @Gino Mempin Ah i see! I will definitely do that. I used the <> button thingy to make it look like code